# GET method in php clean URL

Tags: php, url, get, get-method

I have successfully created clean url for my project.. now what i need to do is add variables to URL..

```
localhost/user1/file?action=add
localhost/user2/file2?action=delete
```

where user and file are already rewritten i dont want it to be like `localhost/user/file/add` because `localhost/user/folder/file` will be mistaken to to the action parameter.. please help

Comment: Have you considered just porting one of the many frameworks that have already solved this problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ampersand instead of question mark:

```
localhost/user2/file2&action=delete
```

In your htaccess, the rewrite rule might look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user([0-9]+)/file([0-9]+)$ /page\.php?user=$1&file=$2
```

As you can see, the question mark is already there even though it is masked in the address bar. Appending another variable to the query string would require the ampersand for successful concatenation.

Comment: problem with some webservices like openID just go back to the url from where it's posted and they add a questionmark. But I understand in this case it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the url and start parsing the url from the question mark. I would save the contents then to an array, so that you've got a key and a value.

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$questionMark = explode('?',$uri);
```

$questionMark[1] is the action=delete then. There are probably better ways then using explode() method here, but I just wanted to show how you get the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can read GET variables in PHP by accessing the global $_GET array:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

In your example, the php file that is used for handling files would be able to read in:

```
echo $_GET['action']; // 'add' or 'delete'
```

Comment: the GET would return nothing. because he already uses a get in the background (mod_rewrite)

Comment: mod_rewrite rewrites the url for the user1/file part. The question was how to deal with the rest. As you can see from AlienWebguy's answer, the page.php?user=$1&file=$2 means that page.php will receive these variables via GET.